# Can a powerline network have multiple internet “input” adapters?

Tags: powerline-networking

I was wondering if a powerline network kan have multiple adapters that are connected to the router/modem? And if that could increase the speed?

My goal is to increase the speed on certain parts of the network that have a slower connection to the primary input device. Will it help to add a second input device closer to the ones that now have the slowest connection?

I have 5 adapters in the network at the moment.

Comment: Yes they can but you should only need one connected to the router.

Comment: Can you share the speed that you see in general or on the slower connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume powerline adapter P1 at the router and P2 at the PC. If you now add P3 to the powerline network and connect it to the router you have a network loop that breaks your network: broadcast packets sent from the router are sent over P1 to P2 and P3, so come back into the router and from there are forwarded again to all local networks, for example to P1, and you have a loop where the packets continue their way through the loop.

You could have two powerline networks. P1 and P2 where P1 is connected to the router and P2 to the PC. And P3 and P4 where P3 is connected to the router and P4 is connected to the PC. Also in this scenario there is potential for a network loop. But even if you don't have a network loop, that setup would not help.

If you have a slow connection then that means that an adapter needs more time to transmit the same amount of traffic. The power coords are a shared medium. So if any adapter is sending, all other adapters cannot send. So if in my second setup P1 is sending, then P3 cannot send in parallel on the shared medium.

So to make it short: no, you can't get better speed when you add more powerline adapters. If you have powerline adapters with 500 Mbps or less it might help to use powerline adapters with 1200 Mbps or 1800 Mbps.